# Finding out the packet number sent over a socket

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

Can someone help on the below issue which troubled us for days? Thanks a lot.

we are developing a library that calculates network traffic over a TCP socket (not raw socket `(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW)` and can know the data stat send/receive) by lib caller actually, but the value is quite different with that from `/proc`.

we are wondering it is caused by packet headers added on the TCP/IP/physical, so it is possible to get the packet number traffic over a socket then we can mend? Or  is there another better way to match the value on `/proc/`.

We cannot calculate based on the uid as lib caller may have other network operations.

Comment: Very difficult to understand your question, but packets don't have packet numbers. TCP *segments* have *sequence* numbers, but they aren't sequential: they are markers in the byte stream.

Comment: sorry, I did not make thing clear. I would like to know the count of packet sent/received over a socket.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. IP headers are wrapped around TCP segments. They aren't extra packets. I also don't understand why you're writing new code when you already have /proc. Evidently you have a bug.

Comment: thanks EJP, our case is that we will provide a lib for android apps,  in lib there is a socket for app to communicate with server with data connection, as the data connection on the phone need spend money, so the lib would like to provide interface for app to get the total count of data in byte sent/received for alert. But we found the count calculated from socket is less than that from /proc/, then we think the reason  may caused the tcp/ip header and would like to know the packet in traffic.

Comment: As I have already said, I think you have a bug in your code, and your guesswork about the IP header doesn't begin to make sense, for reasons which I have also stated here. If you want to progress this matter , you will need to (a) stop repeating yourself, and either (b) post some code here that can be commented on, or (c) devise some new code that inspects `/proc` directly and therefore cannot possibly suffer from whatever bug you have built into your existing code.

Comment: I am sorry that I cannot agree with you it is the bug, anyway, maybe I do not make thing clear.

Answer (score 1):

after dig out kernel's net source, get the tagSocket of qtaguid module, hope it is useful for people similar issues. Enjoy